# How to validate cell only when a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview

I've used `dataGridView1_CellValidating` to check if the user has introduced only numeric values.

However I want the error to appear *only* if the users saves the table - not when they leave the cell.

Is there another method to do this?

I tried to use a variable to check if the button is pressed but it doesn't do anything if the button is pressed and the cell contains wrong data.

Comment: On button click run through all cells and validate them.

Comment: Note that the `visual-studio` tag should only be used for questions relating to Visual Studio, not code you write with it. See the [visual-studio tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info) for more info.

Comment: What do you mean "user saves the table" ? You got a button, and when this button been clicked, all data of the dataGridView1 would be save in a DataTable ? Can't help you in such an ambiguous statement, could you post your codes ?